# endcsname error in the plot command in latex

Tags: pgfplots, csname

I am using the following to plot 2 columns as a line graph.

```
       \begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
    X,     Y      
    05\%,  78.02\%  
    15\%,  76.70\%  
    20\%,  76.30\%  
    50\%,  75.70\%  
    75\%,  70.40\%  
    90\%,  63.90\%
\end{filecontents*}
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend style = { at = {(0.6,0.75)}},
%      unit markings=slash space,
      xlabel=Gender Neutral Pronoun (GNP) Density,
      ylabel=\% of correct predictions on Gold labels,
      xmin=0,xmax=100,
      ymin=60,ymax=80,
      ytick={60,70,...,80},
      xtick={5,20,...,100},
      grid,
      grid style={dotted}]
    
    \addplot [thick, color=blue,
    mark=square,] table {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Results highlighting the impact of varying gender neutral pronoun density in the Entailment split of the training corpus.}
    \end{figure}
```

However for this line

```
 \addplot [thick, color=blue,
    mark=square,] table {data.dat};
```

I see an error that says missing \endcsname or extra \endcsname
What could be the reason?

The logs say:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \%
l.241     mark=square,] table {data.dat};
                                         ^^M
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \%
l.241     mark=square,] table {data.dat};
                                         ^^M
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

Here is a screenshot of logs:

[image: logs]

Comment: please provide a test file we can run to see the error and debug answers. why is this tagged biblatex?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want comma not . to separate the columns

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
    X,     Y      
    05\%,  78.02\%  
    15\%,  76.70\%  
    20\%,  76.30\%  
    50\%,  75.70\%  
    75\%,  70.40\%  
    90\%,  63.90\%
\end{filecontents*}
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend style = { at = {(0.6,0.75)}},
%      unit markings=slash space,
      xlabel=Gender Neutral Pronoun (GNP) Density,
      ylabel=\% of correct predictions on Gold labels,
      xmin=0,xmax=100,
      ymin=60,ymax=80,
      ytick={60,70,...,80},
      xtick={5,20,...,100},
      grid,
      grid style={dotted}]
    
    \addplot [thin] table {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Results highlighting the impact of varying gender neutral pronoun density in the Entailment split of the training corpus.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But is there no way to tell what the error could be about? I can't share the manuscript as a team is working on it, unfortunately.

Comment: well it just failed to parse the data file as a comma separated value file needs commas so you got a low level tex syntax error the exact error isn't very infomative. @AdamRainah

Comment: Updated with logs above^ Please note that I added blue and square markers to the plot line.

Comment: @AdamRainah sure but the errors go if you use comma as shown here don't they?

Comment: No, the error persists with commas too. I actually replaced that section with your snippet.

Comment: @AdamRainah make sure you delete the old data file (it will not over-write) the code here runs without error.